# Python: Can I use Chrome's "Inspect Element" XPath create tool as a Scrapy spider XPath?

Tags: python, google-chrome, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

My spider class is as follows:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name =  "dropzone"
    allowed_domains = ["dropzone.com"]      
    start_urls = ["http://www.dropzone.com/cgi-bin/forum/gforum.cgi?post=4724043"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        reply = response.xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/font/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/font/b')
        dates = response.xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/font/table/tbody/tr/td/font/small')
        items = []
        for posts, day in zip(reply, dates):
            item = DozenItem()
            item["Reply"] = posts.re('/text()')
            item["Date"] = day.re('/text()')
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I selected the item specifically within the source code and right clicked, selecting "Copy XPath" and then just pasted it into my xpath.

BUT..... of course it isn't working. My shell doesn't say it crawled or scraped anything and my CSV is empty.

I originally created my own XPath as I normally do, but it wasn't working either and the Chrome option intrigued me. Normally I only include 3 or 4 tags deep in my XPath. Is this appropriate with the html provided below?

The site is a forum site and I just want to have a self updating scraper that crawls one specific posting for replies to the original post, exporting Date/Post.

The post:

```
http://www.dropzone.com/cgi-bin/forum/gforum.cgi?post=4724043
```

The posts date HTML that I think provides enough tags:

```
<br>
<br>
<!-- FORUM MINI PROFILE -->
Registered: Sep 6, 2012<BR>
Posts: 1850<BR><BR>
</small></font>
 Apr&nbsp;26,&nbsp;2015,&nbsp;7:51&nbsp;AM
<br>
    Post #2 of 11
 (195 views)
<br>
<a href="/cgi-bin/forum/gforum.cgi?post=4724045#4724045">Shortcut</a>
<br>
<img src="http://www.dropzone.com/graphics/forum/clear_shim.gif" width="180" height="1">
</font>
</td>
```

and the Subject of the post itself specifies it is a reply with "Re:" which will remove the original post from being crawled:

```
<td valign="top" width="100%" style="border-left: 1px solid #CCD2DE">
<!-- Adult Content Filter -->
<table border=0 width="100%">
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<font face="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica" size=2 color="#212126">
<b>
 Re: [pleasedtomeet] Skydiving with tinnitus?
</b>
 [<small><a href="#4724043">In reply to</a></small>]
</font>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you need to tweak a bit the Xpath returned by the browsers, for these basic reasons:

1. The HTML can be altered after the page loads by JavaScript.
2. The HTML can be altered by the browser itself.
3. They rely heavily on node position and include many unnecessary elements, ignoring more efficient and change-tolerant selection paths.

For example, the most common browser feature that is guilty for "bad" Xpath is the [`tbody` element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/tbody.html) that gets added to the HTML automatically by the browser, turning this:

```
<table><tr>...</tr></table>
```

into this:

```
<table><tbody><tr>...</tr></tbody></table>
```

Because of this and many other differences in the HTML that you see in the browser and the raw HTML that you get from the server, you should validate your Xpath elements with `scrapy shell` manually prior to implementing them in your spider.

You can find some more info about using developer tools with Scrapy in the  [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/firebug.html?highlight=tbody#using-firebug-for-scraping).

Comment: and the third reason for not unquestioningly accepting such path expressions returned by the browser is that they rely heavily on either the _position_ or _ID_ of nodes - which might not be the ideal XPath expression from a human point of view.

Comment: Well, the position I can agree with - answer updated, but I don't find a more reliable way to select a node than by it's ID. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: That's certainly the best way to identify _individual nodes_. But if your path expression is meant to return a set of nodes that have common properties, then not-so-obvious relationships in the document are important, and they (currently) cannot be automatically inferred by the browser tool. +1 by the way.

Comment: I agree with that, that's mostly the reason I never use auto-generated Xpath; it doesn't suite any real use-case.